# Anima vs. Animus

Tags: meaning, word-comparison

I keep mixing up *animus* and *anima*, and it seems their meanings overlap somewhat. For example, Wiktionary gives the following:

[animus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/animus#Latin): mind, soul, life force; courage, will

[anima](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/anima#Latin): soul, spirit, life; air, breeze; breath

Is there a definitive way to distinguish these words?

Comment: There is a comprehensive explanation here: https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/5775/what-is-the-difference-between-spiritus-and-anima/5783#5783

Comment: @TomCotton. Thanks. What I gather from your answer there is that *animus* refers to human life ("the essential principle" of it), and *anima* doesn't. Is that the main thing to keep in mind?

Comment: That's basically correct, but _anima_ can also mean 'air' or 'breath', in which sense it is used in connection with human (or any animate) life.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both *animus* and *anima* have a broad meaning and mostly overlap. But there's a nuance. They roughly correspond to Spanish ánimo and ánima/alma. *Animus* is more about movement, will, the force that moves, about action, change. Whilst *anima* is more about the inner nature, the force that justifies, about being, about knowing the reasons. The expressions *in animo habeo* for "I have the intention to" and *anima mea* when saying "my beloved one" are good examples.

Comment: I think the distinction became more and more explicit since Christianity for which the concept of soul is crucial and virtually always refered to as _anima_.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with @aper's answer, and would like to add some more color.

To get a general sense and feeling of the difference between *animus* and *anima*, one can consult my Collocation Tool to see what words are usually paired with *animus* and *anima*.

- under [*animus*](https://danelh.github.io/collocations/?lemma=animus&algo=w2) we can see words like *aequus*, *moveo*, *magnitudo*, *magnus*, *bonus*, *fortis*, *induco*, *pertubo*, *rubor*, *dolor*, *cogitatio* and many more.
- under [*anima*](https://danelh.github.io/collocations/?lemma=anima&algo=w2) we find: *caro*, *vivo*, *humanus*, *amitto*, *immortalitas*, *mors*. (those words are not to be find that high in *aminus*).

From that survey one can, I believe, start getting sense of the difference between the terms. *anima* seems to be much more oriented towards the very (base) function of life. hence *amitto/depono/efflo anima* with meaning "to die". While *animus* tends to relate to a higher function of the *human* life like attention and character, feeling, will, etc.; hence *aequo animo* (calmly), or *ab perturbatione animi liberatus* (free from any passion/disturbance of mind). Actually *anima* can be sometimes used to designate life itself and replaceable with *vita*:

> “Difficile est,” inquis, “animum perducere ad contemptionem animae. (Seneca) [It is difficult, you say, to move the *aminum* towards a contempt of *animae* (=life)]

For a more closer and accurate analysis of the differences, one can consult some synonyms dictionaries, one of those which is also in the public domain and available in readable format is of [Döderlein’s](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/33197/33197-h/33197-h.htm#word_Anima2). Thus he writes:

> Anima denotes ‘the soul,’ physiologically, as the principle of animal life, in men and brutes, that ceases with the breath, like ψυχή: animus (ἄνεμος), psychologically and ethically, as the principle of moral personality, that ceases with the will, like θυμός. The souls of the departed also are called, in a mythological point of view, animæ, as shades; but, in a metaphysical point of view, animi, as spirits. Anima is a part of bodily existence; animus, in direct opposition to the body...

Another one, for the Latin readers, is *De differentiis verborum* by Popma, which is similarly available today in a readable edition. After establishing the kind of difference we just mentioned (mainly from examples and other previous sources who already dealt with that question), Popma thus [remarks](https://danelh.github.io/De_Differentiis_Verborum_Popma.pdf#page=36):

> ... Cicero tamen et Seneca saepe dicunt animi immortales, et immortalitas animorum. Hanc differentiam tamen non observat Sall. B. C. I. Immo ipse Cic. frequentissime animum ponit pro anima, v. g. Tusc. Disp. I. 31. Somn. Scip. IV. 3. et 8. ...

Popma basically warns us that this difference is not so set in stone, and should be taken with a grain of salt. He notes that Cicero and Seneca used the expressions *animi immortales* and *immortalitas animorum*(which we would naturally expect to have with *anima* not *animus*), and says that Cicero frequently used *animus* "instead" of *anima*.

More to remember, as @Rafael notes in his comment to other answer, the reader should bear in his mind that the nuances tend to change across time and space.

Comment: Thanks! And thanks also for an introduction ot your Collocation Tool.