# Did the Romans use 'animus' and 'anima' together?

Tags: classical-latin, word-comparison, passage-request

The words *animus* and *anima* are pretty close to each other, and their difference [has been explored on this site before](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/6095/79).
In order to understand their nuances in classical Latin I would like to see an example or two where they are used together.

Are there two words used together in some manner in the extant classical literature?
I am most interested in a use that contrasts the two (e.g. "my *anima* wants to marry this girl but my *animus* wants to run away"), but using them to reinforce each other (e.g. "I want this by my *animus* and *anima*") or together in another way is also of interest.

Comment: Somewhat OT - but distinctions in the sort of the conflict between the "heart" and "mind", such as you describe as an example, are likely to be found not between *anima* and *animus*, but rather between *animus* and *ego*. cf. Syrus: *"Animo imperato ne tibi animus imperet"*. and from Seneca: *"Volo tibi multa alia scribere, sed totus animus in hac una contemplatione defixus est"*. But this needs further investigation, as we may find expressions like *"ex animo volo"*

Comment: @d_e That sounds like a good starting point for a follow-up question. This topic has certainly not been exhausted.

Comment: There are some really good examples in the TLL, https://publikationen.badw.de/en/thesaurus/lemmata#8438 (s.v. animus), e.g.

Comment: @AlexB. That looks very promising! If you or anyone else could post the relevant examples as an answer, even without any discussion, that'd be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lucretius wrote his famous *De Rerum Natura* to propagate the philosophical teachings of Epicurus in Latin.

He makes a big deal of the distinction between the *animus*, which he identifies with mind (*mens*) and places in the chest (*pectus*), and the *anima*, which he calls a "vital heat and wind" (3.128: *calor ac ventus vitalis*) and sees as dispersed throughout the whole body.

The distinction is especially a theme of book III. Here's a pretty long representative passage that places them in contrast:

[*De Rerum Natura* 3.134-60](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0130%3Abook%3D3):

> Nunc animum atque animam dico coniuncta teneri
> inter se atque unam naturam conficere ex se,
> sed caput esse quasi et dominari in corpore toto
> consilium, quod nos animum mentemque vocamus.
> idque situm media regione in pectoris haeret.
> hic exultat enim pavor ac metus, haec loca circum
> laetitiae mulcent: hic ergo mens animusquest.
> cetera pars animae per totum dissita corpus
> paret et ad numen mentis momenque movetur.
> idque sibi solum per se sapit et sibi gaudet,
> cum neque res animam neque corpus commovet una.
> et quasi, cum caput aut oculus temptante dolore
> laeditur in nobis, non omni concruciamur
> corpore, sic animus nonnumquam laeditur ipse
> laetitiaque viget, cum cetera pars animai
> per membra atque artus nulla novitate cietur;
> verum ubi vementi magis est commota metu mens,
> consentire animam totam per membra videmus
> sudoresque ita palloremque existere toto
> corpore et infringi linguam vocemque aboriri,
> caligare oculos, sonere auris, succidere artus,
> denique concidere ex animi terrore videmus
> saepe homines; facile ut quivis hinc noscere possit
> esse animam cum animo coniunctam, quae cum animi vi
> percussa est, exim corpus propellit et icit.

Leonard's [somewhat archaic verse translation](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/785/785-h/785-h.htm) renders this (where *animus* = "mind" and *anima* = "soul"):

> Mind and soul,
> I say, are held conjoined one with other,
> And form one single nature of themselves;
> But chief and regnant through the frame entire
> Is still that counsel which we call the mind,
> And that cleaves seated in the midmost breast.
> Here leap dismay and terror; round these haunts
> Be blandishments of joys; and therefore here
> The intellect, the mind. The rest of soul,
> Throughout the body scattered, but obeys—
> Moved by the nod and motion of the mind.
> This, for itself, sole through itself, hath thought;
> This for itself hath mirth, even when the thing
> That moves it, moves nor soul nor body at all.
> And as, when head or eye in us is smit
> By assailing pain, we are not tortured then
> Through all the body, so the mind alone
> Is sometimes smitten, or livens with a joy,
> Whilst yet the soul's remainder through the limbs
> And through the frame is stirred by nothing new.
> But when the mind is moved by shock more fierce,
> We mark the whole soul suffering all at once
> Along man's members: sweats and pallors spread
> Over the body, and the tongue is broken,
> And fails the voice away, and ring the ears,
> Mists blind the eyeballs, and the joints collapse,—
> Aye, men drop dead from terror of the mind.
> Hence, whoso will can readily remark
> That soul conjoined is with mind, and, when
> 'Tis strook by influence of the mind, forthwith
> In turn it hits and drives the body too.

Answer (score 4):

I did a corpus search for those terms near each other. Cicero discusses something on this topic in the first book of *Tusculanae Disputationes*:

> sed alii in corde, alii in cerebro dixerunt animi esse sedem et locum; animum autem alii animam, ut fere nostri declarat nomen: nam et agere animam et efflare dicimus et animosos et bene animatos et ex animi sententia; ipse autem animus ab anima dictus est

I am not entirely sure about a translation, but PHI and Perseus have this text. It seems that it says in part "The animus itself however is spoken about by the anima". I will edit this answer with a translation when I figure it out.

Comment: Try the Loeb: "But some of them have said that the heart is the local habitation of the soul, whilst others place it in the brain; others however identify soul and breath as we Romans practically do—the name explains this,for we speak of "giving up the ghost" and "expiring" and of "spirited people" and "people of good spirit" and "to the best of one's belief"."

Comment: Clearly, though, the English can't get Latin's nuance across!

Comment: There is some interpunction missing, a [dash](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:abo:phi,0474,049:1:19) after *nostri*. That should clear the grammar up a bit. (In my opinion a full stop would work as well, but what do I know.)