# How would one say 'Spirit Subjugator' or something similar in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

As per the title, I am looking for how you you would say 'Spirit Subjugator' or 'Soul Enslaver' or something similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For "soul", you have a couple options. One of these is *spīritus*. Quoting [Tom Cotton's answer](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/5783/406) to another question:

> *Spiritus* was more tangible, the very ‘breath of life’, the actual ‘life force’, or ‘life principle’. It became symbolic of the spirit by which men might feel themselves driven, and thus the ‘mental spirit’ related to ardour and courage. It was later used for ‘spirit’, ‘soul’ or ‘mind’, and was close in meaning to *mens*, the active faculty of recollection, intellect and understanding.

In Christianity in particular, the Holy Spirit is the *spīritus sanctus*, and when Jesus died he *ēmīsit spīritum*. In the Vulgate, it generally corresponds to Greek *pneuma*, Hebrew *ruahh*, English "spirit".

Another option is *animus*. I don't have as poetic an explanation for it as Tom, but the *animus* is what humans have that animals don't: sentience, consciousness, the rational mind, however you want to put it. It's notably *not* quite the same as *mens*, "mind", since *mens atque animus* "mind and heart" was a common idiom (like English "mind, body, and soul").

In Christianity, this is the usual term for a "soul", as in "the part of a person that isn't the body". In the Vulgate, it generally corresponds to Greek *psychē*, Hebrew *nephesh*, English "soul".

---

For "enslaver" or "subjugator" you also have a few options.

Most literally, the person who sells slaves to people is an *addictor*, with someone who had been legally enslaved (usually for a debt) being *addictus* rather than *servus*.

A more explicit verb is *sub-jugō*, "to put under the yoke (*jugum*)". So a subjugator might be, quite straightforwardly, *subjugātor*. This has a sense of conquering a new territory and selling its people into slavery, rather than just overseeing an auction: it's what Caesar did to Gaul.

---

Grammatically, you'll probably want "subjugator" in the nominative, and "soul" in the genitive plural: *subjugātor* or *addictor*, and *spīrituum* or *animōrum*. Literally, "the subjugator of souls".

Comment: Thank you very much for the lengthy and informative answer!

Answer (score 2):

Subiunctor Animorum, perhaps?
Subiunctor Spirituum?

These are fairly literal translations.

Comment: These are good suggestions, +1! Can you describe the meaning of *subiunctor* for those who haven't seen it before?

Comment: What is the difference between the subiunctor you suggest and subjugātor that Draconis suggested?

Comment: *Subiugator* is an agent who places somebody under a yoke, or ritually humiliates a conquered tribe by forcing them to run the gauntlet under an oxen yoke: from *sub-jugo.*  *Sunjunctor* is a regularly formed word, unattested, to specify an agent who ties a strap under the yoke to fasten it, from *sub-jungo,* to undergird.